# Javascript: an array in While loop isn't changing when it should

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop, increment

I have a while loop that's working fine. Inside it is an array push. yes this part works perfectly until the while loops completes. All of this is inside another while loop what has an increment change. the increment affects the array in hopes to re-write it completely. what ends up happening is that it stays stuck on the first version of the array, and everything else in later coding can't call on the second version of the array.

```
var arrayname = [];
var increment = 0;
var var1 = 0;
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var z = 0;
outerloop == 0;

while(outerloop == 0){    
    endloop = 0;
    while (endloop == 0) {
        arrayname.length = 0;
        randomFunctionThatCreatesThe123variables();//in here 'increment' changes output.
        x = (1 + 2 + 3); //above function's summed result
        y = 25; //static base number
        alert(increment);
        z = (increment + y);
        if (x == z) 
            arrayname[array.length] = [1,2,3];
        if (x == 500)  
            endloop = 1;
    }

    testloop = 0;
    while (testloop == 0){
        otherRandomFunctionsThatTestArray();//this loops the same functions on each subarray
        if (var1 == arrayname.length) {
            testloop = 1; 
            var1 = 0; 
            tar = ++increment;
        }
    }

    if((increment + y) == 700)  
        outerloop = 1; 
}
```

my goal is that the testloop functions test the array, then when endloop recreates the array on the next cycle, it will use the newly incremented affected array. but all that happens is:

if array not cleared:it keeps cycling the tests throught the same array.
if cleared with arrayname.length = 0; the tests use the new increment to find the new array and but finds it undefined.

the alert proves the increment is being properly read.

Comment: @SunilBN where difference between `arrayname = new Array();` and `arrayname = [];`?

Comment: @SunilBN no, do not use `new Array()`; instead prefer the array literal `[]`

Comment: Your code as written does not make a lot of sense to me, esp. the random functions, and statements like `x = (1 + 2 + 3);`. I assume you have tried to simplify your code so you can show us a part of it, but it is only going to cause confusion. Remove everything not directly related to your problem from your sample, and make sure that it can be run stand alone, otherwise it is very hard to help you.

Comment: @SunilBN just in case, i tried the new Array();... no effect.

Comment: the actual coding pulls from several external js files. is there a question i can clear up for you?   the first random function produces a sequence of numbers in a stacked array. the second random function merely pulls information from the stacked arrays and tests them against an entire another external js file.  The 1 + 2 + 3 could be  89 + 1015 + 654 or any numbers for that matter. the x is used to sum them up. as for directly related, aside from the alert, its all directly related.

Comment: "How to change the content of your arrays using a loop and increments."

Comment: What I meant was instead of setting length to 0. You can instantiate ?

Comment: sorry for the fuss. the y = 25; //static base number     turned out to not be as static as thought, ergo not letting the trigger go off. fixed it. works like a beaut now